# Android Studio, problema con edit text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Hola a todos tengo una pregunta estuve siguiendo un tutorial y tengo un problema ANDROID STUDIO, estuve siguiendo este tutorial https://youtu.be/LsKjw-IJQpI y tengo un problema cuando presiono el botón y está vacío, los edittext me para la aplicación quería saber cómo hacer para solucionarlo?

Este es el código:

```
    botonalarma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonalarma);
    botonalarma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int hora = Integer.parseInt(horaedit.getText().toString());
            int minuto = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hora);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minuto);

            if (hora <= 24 && minuto <= 60) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: el siguiente problema es que cuando presiono mi boton y no hay ningun numero se crashea solo funciona si tengo numeros

Comment: ¿Y si validas que haya datos y que éstos sean numéricos enteros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que si no tiene texto el parseInt() te va a dar error. Para escapar este error necesitas comprobar que el texto no sea vacío o meter el parseInt() en un try/catch para escaparlo.

```
//Comprobar si el texto es vacío
botonalarma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonalarma);
    botonalarma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(horaedit.getText().toString() == "" || minuteedit.getText().toString() == "") return;
            int hora = Integer.parseInt(horaedit.getText().toString());
            int minuto = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hora);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minuto);

            if (hora <= 24 && minuto <= 60) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });

//Escapar con try/catch
botonalarma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonalarma);
    botonalarma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
               int hora = Integer.parseInt(horaedit.getText().toString());
               int minuto = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
               Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
               intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hora);
               intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minuto);

               if (hora <= 24 && minuto <= 60) {
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
           }catch(Exception e) {
               //Aquí puedes hacer lo que quieras, mostrar error o mensaje avisando
           }
       }
    });
```

Comment: muchas gracias!me soluciono el problema!!!